# Hive XPATH for dynamic xml tags

Tags: xpath, hive

I have very bad structed large xml to process. Sample code below.

```
  <complex>
<field name="TEST_ATTR">
  <fv>
    <t.0>
      <KOD>12000011</KOD>
      <FLAG>sX</FLAG>
    </t.0>
    <t.1>
      <KOD>s12000021</KOD>
      <FLAG>sN</FLAG>
    </t.1>
    <t.2>
      <KOD>s12000031</KOD>
      <FLAG>sN</FLAG>
    </t.2>
    <t.3>
      <KOD>s12000051</KOD>
      <FLAG>sN</FLAG>
    </t.3>
    <t.4>
      <KOD>s12000061</KOD>
      <FLAG>sN</FLAG>
    </t.4>
    <t.5>
      <KOD>s12000071</KOD>
      <FLAG>sN</FLAG>
    </t.5>
    <t.6>
      <KOD>s12000081</KOD>
      <FLAG>sN</FLAG>
    </t.6>
  </fv>
</field>
</complex>
```

Question 1:
How can I extract from this xml node name like t.0 etc??
Using XPATH or some other utils?!

Question 2:
How to get value of `<KOD>` tag using dynamic XPATH?
example: 
`complex/fieldfv/*/KOD` where `'*'` means ANY.

Comment: what version of xpath?

Comment: #---- BEGIN writeEnvironmentReport($Revision: 1.10 $): Useful stuff found: ----
java.version=1.8.0_51
version.xalan2x=not-present
version.JAXP=1.4
java.ext.dirs=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
version.SAX=2.0
version.crimson=not-present
java.class.path=.
version.ant=not-present
version.DOM=3.0
version.xalan1=not-present
version.xalan2_2=Xalan Java 2.7.0
version.xerces2=Xerces-J 2.7.1
version.xerces1=not-present

Comment: Sorry whose are my settings up here!

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

Since it looks like you are using Java to execute your XPath, it sounds like your best option is to select the elements with the non-consistent names, iterate over them, and use the DOM API to get the element name.

You can use this XPath to select them:

```
/complex/field/fv/*
```

When iterating over them (as [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) objects), you can use the `.getNodeName()` to get the name of each one.

**Question 2:**

Yes, you can use this XPath to select all of the KOD elements:

```
/complex/field/fv/*/KOD
```

However, if you are iterating over the `t.0`, `t.1`, etc. nodes as suggested in the answer to Question1, a better approach would be to use each of those respective elements as the starting point to select the `KOD` element within them, using a relative XPath:

```
KOD
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.